# Secure multiparty computation protocols for stable matching?

Tags: multiparty-computation

Are you aware of papers proposing secure multiparty computation protocols for stable matching problems such as [Stable Roommates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem) and [Stable Marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) problems?

Specifically, I would like the ranking of each party to be kept private and either reveal the whole output to everybody (all the pairings) or just reveal each pairing to the involved parties.

Comment: It can be done using a general MPC protocol, but I'm assuming you want something more efficient?

Comment: Yes, if it is not available yet, I would like to develop something ad-hoc that is efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for? 
[Secure Stable Matching at Scale](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/861) by Jack Doerner, David Evans, and abhi shelat.